# code has not effect under for loop python odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am running a simple code to open the generate_invoice view if i indent it under the for and if statement it's not working. does anyone know what i am missing?

Here is my code

Objective: The code job is to open generate_invoice view if in the payment structure has any entry, the for loop is checking if there is any account if yes then return the view if not raise validation error.

```
class res_student(models.Model):
_name = 'res.student'
```

This Code is not working no error.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('payment_structure')
def generate_invoice(self):
    for x in self:
        for rec in x.payment_structure:
            if rec.account == False:
                raise ValidationError("Please define a payment structure to Generate Invoice")
            else:
                form = self.env['generate.invoice']
                id = self.id
                record = form.create({'student_id': id,
                                      'journal': x.journal.id,
                                      'payment_type': x.payment_account.id})
                return {'name': "Generate Invoice",
                                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                                'res_model': 'generate.invoice',
                                'view_id': False,
                                'view_type': 'form',
                                'view_mode': 'form',
                                'res_id' : record.id,
                                'target': 'new',
                                'domain': '[]'}
```

If i remove the for and if statement then working.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('payment_structure')
def generate_invoice(self):
   form = self.env['generate.invoice']
   id = self.id
   record = form.create({'student_id': id,
                          'journal': x.journal.id,
                           'payment_type': x.payment_account.id})
   return {'name': "Generate Invoice",
           'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'generate.invoice',
            'view_id': False,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_id' : record.id,
            'target': 'new',
             'domain': '[]'} 

#accounting
journal = fields.Many2one('account.journal')
payment_account = fields.Many2one('nominal.account')
payed = fields.Float(compute="get_payment")
discount = fields.Float(compute="get_discount")
payments = fields.One2many('invoice.line','student_id')
payment_structure = fields.One2many('payment.structure','student_id')




class payment_structure(models.Model):
_name = "payment.structure"

student_id = fields.Many2one('res.student')
account = fields.Many2one('nominal.account')
qty = fields.Integer()
unit = fields.Selection([('once','Once'),('month','Month')])
price = fields.Float()


class generate_invoice(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'generate.invoice'



student_id = fields.Many2one('res.student')
month = fields.Integer(string="Months")
payment_type = fields.Many2one('nominal.account', related="student_id.payment_account", )
payment_structure = fields.One2many(related="student_id.payment_structure")
journal = fields.Many2one('account.journal')
```

Comment: Please edit your code, it does not look right. Also, describe "it's not working". Are you getting an error? No output? A different output than expected?

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference from sale order,

in which you can find this button "Create and View Invoice"

from there may you got solution,because I checked this code and your code there is some difference there.
so please try this.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove for loop in your generate_invoice function, you'll get error because variable 'x' is not defined.

Please show us when was the generate_invoice function is called, and the contain of self in it.